# OSX: X11 Connection Rejected

Tags: macos, x11-forwarding, xquartz

The message below is received when accessing a RHEL server from OSX.

The latest XQuartz is running on the OSX (Mavericks) - any ideas on where to troubleshoot? I have Googled the heck out of this issue to no avail.

*[root@foo bin]# ./389-console
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Console: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:11.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "accessing a RHEL server", so I assume you're accessing thru the Mac's Terminal, maybe w/ rlogin or ssh?  These are on the same network?  In other words, the RHEL is not off at a friend's or an ISP and you Mac is at home behind a firewall/router?  If so, get the IP address of the Mac, and after you rlogin/ssh to the RHEL, explicitly set the display back to your Mac, like `setenv DISPLAY 10.0.1.1:0` (tcsh syntax).  You might also want to type `xhost +` on the Mac first.

After that, it should work.  If it does, you might want to replace `xhost +` with the proper command to just allow the RHEL to connect to the Mac's X server, instead of allowing everyone to connect.